# Why doesn't variable update

Tags: c++, oop, variables

I am practising c++ OOP and I expected a private variable inside a class to be updated after setting it with a public function but nothing happened. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class HideAndSeek
{
    private:
        string isHidden = "N";

    public:
        string getHiddenStatus()
        {
            string hiddenStatus = isHidden;
            return hiddenStatus;
        }

        void setHiddenStatus(string hiddenStatus)
        {
            isHidden = hiddenStatus;
        }
};

int main()
{
    HideAndSeek yayOrNay; //HideAndSeek object instance

    string f = yayOrNay.getHiddenStatus(); //Gets the value of private isHidden in HideAndSeek class
    cout << f << endl; //Value of f should be "N"

    yayOrNay.setHiddenStatus("Y"); //This should set isHidden to "Y"
    cout << f << endl; //Value of f should now be "Y"

}
```

The string variable f outputs "N" on both occasions even though its value should have been changed to "Y" with

```
yayOrNay.setHiddenStatus("Y");
```

Also I found that calling

```
yayOrNay.getHiddenStatus()
```

to variable f again

```
f = yayOrNay.getHiddenStatus();
```

yields proper output but I think that's one too many steps to update a variable value. Can anyone please help point out my error?

Comment: What does `int a = 5; int b = a; a = 6; cout << b;` print?

Comment: immibis 
b will == 5

Comment: The reason b is 5 is the same reason f is "N" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling setHiddenStatus() does not change the value of f.

f was assigned the return value of getHiddenStatus() and will not change unless you give it a new value.

Answer (score 5):

`getHiddenStatus` returns a **copy** so `f` has its own version of the string which will not update when `isHidden` is changed.

To make `f` *track* the value of `isHidden`, return a *reference* to it:

```
string& getHiddenStatus() { return isHidden; }
      ^
```

and

```
string& f = yayOrNay.getHiddenStatus(); 
      ^
```

If `isHidden` should not be changed via the reference, make it a `const` reference:

```
const string& getHiddenStatus() const { return isHidden; }
```

and

```
const string& f = yayOrNay.getHiddenStatus();
```

Now trying to change `isHidden` via `f` results in a compile error:

```
f = "bwahaha";
```

(The `const` between `getHiddenStatus()` and `{` makes the function itself `const`. It tells the
                                          compiler and readers of the code that
                                          `getHiddenStatus` doesn't modify `HideAndSeek`,
                                          so that you can call it on a `const HideAndSeek` object.)